# Что не так с SQL запросом? Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Когда исполняю подобный код в DB Browser всё работает как нужно.
Однако в Python выдаёт ошибку -> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: True
В чём проблема?

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_date = (" '" + str(now.day) + ':' + str(now.month) + ':' + str(now.year) + "' ")
        users_db.execute("UPDATE members SET paid = False, date_of_removal =" + str(now_date) + "WHERE (days_left = 0 AND paid = True)")
```

Comment: Какой тип поля `paid`?

Comment: paid  = Text, date_of_removal  =  Text, days_left = int

Comment: Тогда `SET paid = 'False'` и `AND paid = 'True'`

Comment: Используйте [параметризованные](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/5045688) запросы.

Answer (score 0):

В sqlite3 нет boolean типа данных.  Вместо них используется integer 0 или 1.

Поэтому paid = True - неверная конструкция, если у вас нет поля `True`

Answer (score 0):

Sergey Gornostaev подсказал правильный вариант в комментариях. Спасибо.

SET paid = 'False' и AND paid = 'True'